# What exactly the bad consequences are when using `main()` instead `WinMain()` in a Windows GUI application?

Tags: c++, winapi

[There is an article about entry point on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406(v=vs.85).aspx) which contains a warning about using `main()` instead of `WinMain()`.

> The CRT does some additional work inside main. For example, any static initializers are called before wWinMain. Although you can tell the linker to use a different entry-point function, use the default if you link to the CRT. Otherwise, the CRT initialization code will be skipped, with unpredictable results. (For example, global objects will not be initialized correctly.)

Unfortunately I could't find any information about what exactly the bad consequences are if I use `main()` instead of `WinMain()` in an application with windows subsystem setting.

Does anyone can tell, or how can I find it out on my own ? 
Sincerely thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't care about the specific bad consequences - they could get worse in a future version of the CRT.  The critical thing is the "if you link to the CRT" criteria: if you do link it, make sure you're initialising it properly.

Comment: For starters, a console window will popup on the desktop if you launch the EXE from Explorer.

Comment: The warning goes against providing an entry point yourself, sidestepping the CRT's startup code. One of the bad consequences is explicitly spelled out (and quoted by yourself): Sidestepping the CRT's startup code leads to skipping initializers for global objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking about the consequences of violating a documented contract when there is **zero** reason to violate that contract is not a practical programming question.

Comment: Apparently you are not adequately familiar with the CRT. You can learn more about the CRT then attempt to find answers to anything not adequately explained then ask questions **if you need to** about anything not clear. As @IInspectable says, you don't explain why you **need** to understand what the CRT is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really trust that documentation, `main` does not call `WinMain`. The issue it is trying to warn against is when you override the CRTs entry point function with the /ENTRY linker switch. If you do that then the CRT is not going to be initialized correctly and constructors might not be called.

At the Windows ABI layer, if [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.Subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) is set to `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI` then a new console/terminal is created unless the parent process already has a console. The caller of `CreateProcess` can override this with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` and other flags.

When the process is started, Windows just calls the entry point function (`AddressOfEntryPoint`) and this function does not have any parameters.

When using the Microsoft linker this function is called [`mainCRTStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) when creating a console application and `WinMainCRTStartup` when creating a GUI application. If you are using the C run-time/CRT then these functions are provided for you and call `main` or `WinMain` respectively. Either way, the special magic is performed before **your** entry point function is called.

A console application is allowed to create normal windows and a GUI application can create consoles (`AllocConsole`). Which type you choose just depends on if you want a console to be created for you. Additional work is required if you want to associate `stdout` with a console you manually create.

My recommendation is to just use `main` in your code for console applications and `WinMain` in GUI applications, the linker and CRT will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this answered my question! In fact I found the source code of CRT on my hard drive(for me it's `MSVC/14.xx/crt/src/vcruntime/exe_common.inl:52`), indeed it's doing almost the same thing for both main and `WinMain` or others. Wondering who's writting the confusing MSDN documents, anyway, Thank you again! Also to other people who replied, thanks too!

Comment: One more question, I can't really choose wether to use the CRT or not, can I? CRT is binding to you when you programing Windows in c++ with MSVC compiler, right? Is another working sandard library implement for MSVC compiler out there?

Comment: Sorry for asking again. I tried to build a GUI application with `main` instead of `WinMain`, if I set the subsystem to windows instead of console in Visual Studio, It just give me a linker error complaining unsolved symbol `_WinMain` in `MSVCRTD.lib`, unless I set subsystem back to `console`. Can you compile a application which subsystem is setted to `windows` instead of `console` with `main` function instead of `WinMain`? If you can, how should I fix the linker error?

Comment: You can compile without CRT, add /Zl  and remove /MT or /MD compiler switches and create your own *CRTStartup function (See http://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size#). It makes no sense to have a main function and no console. If you want a console, build a console app, if not, build a GUI app. Call `CommandLineToArgvW` if you want argv+argc in a GUI app..

Comment: @shawn-young: You cannot write C++ code without a runtime library. A lot of C++ features are implemented in runtime code (e.g. part of the stack unwinding code for exception handling). If you remove the CRT, there's not much left you can do.

Comment: @IInspectable: Perhaps you can't write C++ code without *a* runtime library, but you can write C++ code without *the* vendor-supplied runtime library. That an important distinction to make. And no, I'm not saying it's prudent or necessarily useful. Just possible. Another important distinction people tend to forget or ignore.

Comment: @conio: That distinction is hardly ever relevant in practice, though. CRT and compiler are usually highly dependent on each other. Using the vendor supplied runtime is in the vast majority of cases the only option there is.

Comment: Not everyone uses the STL and exceptions. Templates, classes, operator-overloading and other basic c++ features work fine without CRT (You do have to do some work for operator new and global constructors and destructors though). Windows c++ kernel drivers are also written with this kind of c++ subset.

Comment: @IInspectable: It was important enough for someone to ask about it. The Library Manager and the COFF Binary File Dumper are also "highly dependent" on the compiler etc. and are actually bundled with the compiler and the CRT. They are enough to make the statement that using the "supplied runtime" is "the only option there is" completely false.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in the quote.  CRT initialization code won't run, so its global objects won't be initialized.  The CRT initialization code is also responsible for initializing your program's global objects, so they won't be initialized either.

Anything that depends on this initialization may fail or misbehave.  Nobody's going to document all the specifics of what those are, because it's going to vary by implementation.  But you could easily imagine things like heap allocation (malloc, free, new, delete, etc.) depend on initialization, as might i/o to the standard handles (stdout, cout, etc.)  You cannot come up with a complete list, but it should be obvious that depriving important subsystems of their initialization is going to make it very difficult to build a working, non-trivial program.

Since you seem to be asking specifically about Windows, I'll assume you're using Visual C++ and its runtime libraries.  Note that Visual C++ includes the sources of the runtime libraries.  You can step through the initialization code in the debugger to see the types of work it does before passing control to WinMain.

Comment: ...except that the quote is incorrect. The CRT cannot do anything inside main because main is a function you provide. The CRT does some work before it calls _your_ main/WinMain function.

Comment: @Anders:  Yes, the documentation there is pretty sloppy with the terminology.  The paragraph before the quoted one is similarly buggy but conveys the gist.  Nevertheless, the quoted text, despite the bad wording does answer the question of what bad things happen:  initialization is skipped.